# V8 assertion `Debug check failed: ThreadId::Current().Equals(compilation_info()->isolate()->thread_id())` failed

Tags: multithreading, chromium, v8

I'm working on integration of some third-party product into Chromium (Android) that is working in Browser process (main).
The product uses Chromium's V8 and is creating new `Isolate` using `IsolateHolder`:

```
// thread
thread = new base::Thread("MyProductThread");
thread->Start();

#ifdef V8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA
LOG(WARNING) << "MyProduct: loading v8 snapshot & natives ...";
gin::V8Initializer::LoadV8Snapshot();
gin::V8Initializer::LoadV8Natives();
LOG(WARNING) << "MyProduct: loaded v8 snapshot & natives";
#endif

LOG(WARNING) << "MyProduct: initialize isolate holder";
gin::IsolateHolder::Initialize(gin::IsolateHolder::kNonStrictMode,
                               gin::IsolateHolder::kStableV8Extras,
                               gin::ArrayBufferAllocator::SharedInstance());

isolate_holder = new gin::IsolateHolder(
  thread->task_runner(),
  gin::IsolateHolder::AccessMode::kUseLocker);
isolate_holder->isolate()->Enter();

LOG(WARNING) << "MyProduct: created isolate holder";

// return isolate pointer
v8::Isolate* isolate = isolate_holder->isolate();
```

I'm creating new Thread in order not to block UI as the code is invoked from main thread (from Android's activity that is forwarded to C++ via generated JNI).

Then sometimes it crashes with the following:

> ... E/v8: #
>                                        # Fatal error in ../../v8/src/compiler.cc, line 87
>
> Debug check failed: ThreadId::Current().Equals(compilation_info()->isolate()->thread_id())

What does it mean?

A bit limited stack trace:

```
Stack Trace:


RELADDR   FUNCTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               FILE:LINE
  000161d5  gin::(anonymous namespace)::PrintStackTrace()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          /home/antoine/chromium/src/gin/v8_platform.cc:55
  0000d051  V8_Fatal(char const*, int, char const*, ...)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/base/logging.cc:123
  0022eca5  v8::internal::CompilationJob::PrepareJob()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler.cc:86
  00235733  v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::PrepareAndExecuteUnoptimizedCompileJob(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::FunctionLiteral*, v8::internal::Isolate*)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler.cc:387
  0022fe25  v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GenerateUnoptimizedCode(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::Isolate*, std::__ndk1::forward_list<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<v8::internal::CompilationJob, std::__ndk1::default_delete<v8::internal::CompilationJob> >, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<v8::internal::CompilationJob, std::__ndk1::default_delete<v8::internal::CompilationJob> > > >*)                             /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler.cc:413
  00231f13  v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CompileToplevel(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::Isolate*)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler.cc:786
  0023358d  v8::internal::Compiler::GetSharedFunctionInfoForScript(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, int, v8::ScriptOriginOptions, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, v8::Extension*, v8::internal::ScriptData**, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions, v8::internal::NativesFlag, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArray>)  /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/compiler.cc:1331
  000ff8f1  v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnboundInternal(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/api.cc:2314
  00100299  v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   /home/antoine/chromium/src/v8/src/api.cc:2373
  00102047  v8::Script::Compile(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::ScriptOrigin*)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  /data/app/org.chromium.chrome-1/lib/arm/libv8.cr.so
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

PS. I'm using not the latest revision of Chromium, but i don't think it's the reason for the issue.

PPS. I've tried to use some of existing background threads (with `content::BrowserThread::GetTaskRunnerForThread(content::BrowserThread::FILE)`) and even create `Isolate` in the background thread and pass it as `IsolateHolder` argument - no luck.

Comment: Note clear why this is tagged [embedded] - may not be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isolate_holder->isolate()->Enter();` was not required and even hurting (as it's done by the library which is using that `Isolate` instance) but affecting much later.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to have a V8 instance run on a background thread, while calling into it from the main thread (the end of your code snippet returns an `Isolate*` pointer -- to the main thread, I presume?). That is not supported.

You can certainly have V8 live on the background thread, but then you'll need to ensure that all V8 API calls happen on that same background thread. You'll have to implement the cross-thread communication logic yourself (possibly using Chromium's existing `PostTask` etc primitives).

Comment: I would agree V8 to run in any thread, either main or background. I've tried to use main thread for both creation of Isolate instance and invocation but it because of assertion failure. I will double check invocation comes from main thread too. Is it correct that both Isolate and invocation are required to be done in the same thread?

Comment: BTW isn't using `gin::IsolateHolder::AccessMode::kUseLocker);` not enough for multithreading (invoking V8 methods from different threads) possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with `gin::IsolateHolder` to answer that with certainty. Generally speaking, if you need to interact with a `V8::Isolate` from different threads, you have to use explicit locking to make sure that only one thread is active at a time -- not just a single `isolate()->Enter()` up front! Usually it's preferable/easier to only interact with the `Isolate` from one thread.